# Flying to India with one month left on Indian passport

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india

I am an Indian citizen (valid Indian passport holder.)
I will be travelling to India from the gulf on a family emergency 7th of August  … and I checked and saw my passport will expire in just over a month (around Mid September 2023). Can I be denied entry to India (my country)?

Comment: Is there anything about official this on a Indian government website confirming that Indian citizens won’t be denied entry into India provided they arrive in India before the expiry date of the passport … it’s something I want to have with me when I check in so I won’t be denied boarding by the Airline … I can’t seem to find anything on this online and would appreciate some help with a link ; thanks

Comment: No, a citizen cannot generally be denied entry to their own country. The bigger issue is whether you're going to run into any trouble upon returning, as the Gulf country may have passport validity requirements. Which country is this?

Comment: No airline in the world is going to think you need anything more than 1 day validity to travel to your country of citizenship.  You're worrying about something that simply isn't a thing.